# how can isolev this proplem A problem occurred evaluating root project 'i_am_rich'. > Cannot add task 'clean' as a task with that name already exists

Tags: android, flutter, dart

C:\Users\Leen\Pictures[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opwgM.png)

[`

enter image description here

`][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VznCc.png)

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as images.

Answer (score 1):

Flutter is case sensitive, so e.g. Container is correct while container os wrong. And you've spelled `package` as well as `material.dart` wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please make a flutter project.
Then You will have all the widgets available to work with and you can also run your app.

For creating project on Android Studion Go to file, create new project, choose flutter form there, give your project name and create your project.

Comment: I tried to do it and it giving me errors

Comment: and it doesn't give me suggestions for running app or widget

Comment: and file main .dart is not created i created it and can i ask one more question which language should i use kotlin or java

Comment: Bro, first of all, you have to download the flutter SDK, For developing apps with flutter you need to learn the "Dart" programming language. After installing Flutter sdk, you have to choose which code editor you are gonna use, Then in that code editor install flutter extension, and you have to create a flutter project to start building flutter apps.  Here is a link to start => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDnqXmLSqtg